# Why only 5 reputation points for an upvote to a question?

Tags: support, questions, up-votes

I just received the second upvote for my question, *[How to develop one Android application for different screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036369/how-to-develope-one-android-application-for-different-screens)*

I got only 5 reputation points whereas for my previous upvote for the same question I got 10 reputation points. I observed the same problem for some other questions also.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Cody Gray, this is not a duplicate. It's the opposite of the question you link to. Easy on the trigger finger there, Tejas.

Comment: But now you will get +10 for upvotes of your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391250/9801830

Answer (score 17):

It shows the sum of all upvotes you got per question. In total you got two upvotes. If you hover over the "upvote" text for each row, it tells you how many upvotes that row represents.

---

*"set transparent background of an imageview in Android"* is an answer, which gets +10 reputation per upvote.

*"How to develop one Android application for different screens?"* is a question, which gets +5 per upvote.

Comment: Worth mentioning, Questions and Answers have different colors in the reputation tab display.

Comment: @Matt okk got it.. Upvote for a `Question` gets 5 points and Upvote for an `Ansewer` gets 10 points.